# View content of H2 in-memory database in JBoss EAP 6.2

Tags: database, web, jboss, h2, jboss-eap-6

My web application run on jboss eap 6.2 and store data to h2 im-memory database.

This is the datasource configuration in standalone.xml of jboss:

```
        <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
            <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
            <driver>h2</driver>
            <security>
                <user-name>sa</user-name>
                <password>sa</password>
            </security>
        </datasource>
```

When i use the H2 database engine (http://www.h2database.com/html/download.html) to access my database but I can't find my table in it, it only have the INFORMATION_SCHEMA with default tables.

So how can I view the content of database?

p/s: I have created web project using maven with archetype

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.jboss.aerogear.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=jboss-html5-mobile-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=7.1.3.CR6 -Denterprise=true
```

Thank you!

Comment: Did you set the tables to be automatically created in your persistence.xml Otherwise they aren't there ofc.

Comment: yes, I set "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" to "create-drop". When I connect to mysql, it's still ok